# How do I access attribute in a (sort-of) complex json object?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get at the attribute for a (somewhat) complex json object but am having no luck.

The json object itself looks like this, generated from a query:

```
{
 "displayFieldName": "REPNAME",
 "fieldAliases": {
  "DISTRICT": "DISTRICT",
  "REPNAME": "REPNAME"
 },
 "fields": [
  {
   "name": "DISTRICT",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
   "alias": "DISTRICT"
  },
  {
   "name": "REPNAME",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "REPNAME",
   "length": 150
  }
 ],
 "features": [
  {
   "attributes": {
    "DISTRICT": 21,
    "REPNAME": "Ira Anders"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I went to json2csharp.com to generate C# classes from that json and got this:

```
public class FieldAliases
{
    public string DISTRICT { get; set; }
    public string REPNAME { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public int? length { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    public int DISTRICT { get; set; }
    public string REPNAME { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string displayFieldName { get; set; }
    public FieldAliases fieldAliases { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get at the "attributes" object and have it return DISTRICT and REPNAME (which should be 21 and Ira Anders). I've tried it the following methods:

Using DataContractJsonSerializer class - have tried 3 or 4 different ways to doing this, but it still doesn't work

```
Attributes attr = new Attributes();
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MoRepjson));
stream1.Position = 0;
DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Attributes));
attr = deserializer.ReadObject(stream1) as Attributes;
string dist = attr.DISTRICT.ToString();
string repname = attr.REPNAME;
stream1.Close();
```

I've also tried us the javaScriptSerializer class, it also doesn't work:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Attributes attr = ser.Deserialize<Attributes>(MoRepjson);
string dist = attr.DISTRICT.ToString();
string repname = attr.REPNAME;
```

And then using JSON.NET library - Doesn't work again:

```
Attributes attr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Attributes>(MoRepjson);
string dist = attr.DISTRICT.ToString();
string repname = attr.REPNAME;
```

The string "dist" and "repname" variables are on my web page. For some reason, when I run it, DISTRICT usually shows a "0" (as my json above shows it should show a 21). Have no idea where or how it gets a zero. The REPNAME variable shows something blank.

If I create a mind-numbing simple json object hard-coded object such as ...

```
Attributes attr = new Attributes { DISTRICT = 9999, REPNAME = "Some Representative" };
```

... I have no problem accessing DISTRICT and REPNAME (such as repname = attr.REPNAME). It's only when I try to access my actual/real json that I have problems.

The only thing I've sort-of gotten to "work" is by accessing the RootObject such as ...

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(MoRepjson);
string test = ro.displayFieldName;
```

... which correctly displays "REPNAME" (though I'm not sure why it's showing REPNAME and not DISTRICT). However, if I try to get deeper into the whole json object by doing something like ...

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(MoRepjson);
string test = ro.features.???
```

... I run into a brick wall. Just for the heck of it I tried replacing ...

```
public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
```

... in my RootObject with ...

```
public Feature features { get; set; }
```

... but that doesn't work either.

I don't actually care about the other classes except Attributes, but when I try to directly access an Attributes object it comes up empty. Once I also did get a (correct) count of "1" when I got a count of RootObject, so I know it's returning *something*, I just don't know how to get at it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is that you have a root object, with a `features` list, where each `Feature` has an `attributes` property.

If you only want all the attributes, just use the following:

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(MoRepjson);
var attributes = rootObject.features.Select(f => f.attributes);

foreach (var a in attributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DISTRICT: " + a.DISTRICT);
    Console.WriteLine("REPNAME: " + a.REPNAME);
}
```

Test it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CliXDW

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `MoRepjson` is the Json you posted.  Since it represents a RootObject, you have to deserialize it as RootObject.  Deserializing it as anything else doesn't make sense.

secondly, what you get out of that is a whole MoRepjson object.  which contains a `List<>` of features.  you access individual ones like this.

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(MoRepjson);
List<Feature> features = ro.features;
Feature firstFeature = features[0];
Attributes attributes = firstFeature.attributes;
string repname = attributes.REPNAME;
```

Above is simplistic code to demonstrate the structure of the object that results from the Json.  In practice, you'd do something like this.

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(MoRepjson);

var firstAttributes rootObject.features
    .Select(x => x.attributes)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if(firstAttributes != null)
{
    string repName = firstAttributes.REPNAME;
    int district = firstAttributes.DISTRICT;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Except I had to make test a global public object. Thanks! Undoubtedly something else will go wrong now. :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a specific value, it's much simpler to use [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string json = ...
var root = JObject.Parse(json);
var fieldAliases = root["fieldAliases"];
string district = fieldAliases["DISTRICT"].Value<string>();
string repName  = fieldAliases["REPNAME"].Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Now I'm getting another error, and it doesn't seem to be popping up consistently. Seems to be happening with both the solutions ppl posted above. It only produces the error at runtime, not a build error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0101: The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'Attributes'

Then it points to the two lines:

```
public class Attributes
```

and

```
public int DISTRICT { get; set; }
```

But it's not popping up consistently, I'll make no changes and suddenly it works.

Comment: This looks to be a second question.  If so, you should ask another question, as the preferred format on stackoverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).  Or, if this is a clarification to your original question, you should edit that question.  In any event it's extremely unlikely that anybody will notice your additional question embedded in this answer, and try to answer it.